# Android Studio Arctic Fox Flavor Dimension Issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavordimension

It's my first encounter with flavor dimensions. I am trying to compile a ready-made code but somehow I ended up with this issue.

ERROR:

```
    All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
Affected Modules: app
```

here is my build.gradle:app

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adit.bangkit.plagroid"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    productFlavors {
        sandbox {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://plagro.000webhostapp.com/payment.php/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_KEY", "\"SB-Mid-client-zS17TygMBI02Ta0o\""
        }
        production {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://plagro.000webhostapp.com/payment.php/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_KEY", "\"Mid-client-GtpJDccjfv7lVXis\""
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'

    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0"
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2"
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"

    // KTX for the Maps SDK for Android
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-ktx:3.2.1'

    // (Optional) KTX for the Maps SDK for Android Utility Library
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android-common:3.1.0'

    //midtrans payment
    implementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.28.0-SANDBOX'
}
```

I am sorry for being a noob and really don't know how to solve this. If someone had a solution please help me with this.this issue happend after i add midtrans payment library.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors) from the error, you should add a flavour dimension. According to the documentation from that link

> All flavors must belong to a named flavor dimension, which is a group
> of product flavors. You must assign all flavors to a flavor dimension;
> otherwise, you will get the build error shown below. If a given module
> specifies only one flavor dimension, the Android Gradle plugin
> automatically assigns all of the module's flavors to that dimension.

In the example from the link they add

```
flavorDimensions "version"
```

And below, in your productFlavor tags you could add

```
dimension "version"
```

Or if you don't need more than one dimension you can ignore this last part.

Comment: i already done it but i got another error, here is the error message  'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:sandboxDebugCompileClasspath'.'

Comment: and here is the another error message org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:sandboxDebugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: could you provide your new Gradle file?